# Facebook API 1.0 new platform

Tags: facebook, api

Just want to make sure I understand how the Facebook API versioning policy works with v1.0 deprecation.  If I have an existing Facebook app that was created prior to April 30th 2014, can I create a new platform (e.g. IOS or Android) today and still use the v1.0 API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Platforms don´t matter, if your App was created before April 30, 2014 and if it was active before that date, you can still use v1.0 until April 30, 2015.